# SOAP library for Qt

Tags: c++, qt, soap

I am developing an application at the moment(using C++/Qt4.8), and I want to implement 'ideone.com' support.

The problem is that ideone.com API is based on SOAP protocol.

Is there any good library for Qt(or just C++) for this purpose(it has to be cross-platform)? 
The only library I found is Qt Soap, but it seems to be discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [HTTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122508/qt-http-server). [This solution somewhat better.](http://stefanfrings.de/qtwebapp/index-en.html) Based on that projects you could create an own SOAP service.

A SOAP example on [github](https://github.com/commontk/QtSOAP).